# Lightning bolt on battery disappears after hibernation

Tags: 16.04, suspend, indicator, battery, hibernate

This is a small problem (doesn't seriously affect my work) but whenever I return from suspend/hibernate the lightning bolt on the battery icon is gone (the one that indicates it's charging). It is, in fact, charging and the battery icon appears, but without the lightning bolt. Also, unplugging and plugging it again (without shutting down), doesn't fix the issue. The only fix that works is to shutdown or restart.

> My specs:
>
> - OS: Ubuntu 16.04
> - kernel: 4.12.0-041200-generic
> - Laptop Model: ASUS ROG Strix GL753VD